# If this string appears in my column, then overwrite the information in my other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am dealing with this issue at the moment. Let's consider we have 2 columns (column A and column B). In column A I have a reference number and in Column B I have a string.

In column B, some rows will contain the term 'co-load' and next to it will have a reference number similar to the reference number in column A (but not identical).

Can I then copy the reference number for all occurrences with 'co-load' (10% of the data) by using a function in SQL Server and "paste" it onto the reference number in column A which is not longer valid?

As you can see in the image there is still some information left that is being copied into the new column. How can I avoid this?

```
 select MM.MovementRef, ME.MovementReference, replace(MU.Number, 'co-load', '') as change, MU.Number as trailername 
 from dbo.MALExport AS MEME.MovementReference
    INNER JOIN dbo.movConLink AS MCL ON ME.ConsignmentReference = MCL.ConsignmentReference
    INNER JOIN dbo.cgtRoute AS CR ON RouteID = CMRRouteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.movMovement AS MM ON MM.MovementRef = 
    LEFT  JOIN dbo.movUnit AS MU ON MU.UnitID = MM.TrailerID 
    where MU.Number like '%co-load%'
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do an update.  As you describe it, you can use string operations, such as:

```
update t
    set a = replace(b, 'co-load', '')
    where b like '%co-load%';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have tried to apply your suggestion but I am still struggling. Any ideas on this? I simply want to obtain that NT number.

Comment: I think I am basically after a function that "replaces everything except for ..." any ideas?